# JQuery plugin for infinite up scrolling?

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite

I actually wanted to ask if a front-end plugin is really necessary for implementing infinite scroll?  and relatedly I wanted to ask if anyone knows if any of the JQuery based infinite scroll plugins support scrolling up to retrieve more content.  Would implementing infinite scrolling to load data when the user scrolls up, rather than down, just be a setting in some plugin, or the some specification of the horizontal point that the user has to scroll to, in order to load content?
Sorry if this seems obvious to everyone else, this is the first time that I would be implementing it.

Comment: Having built a *bi-directional* infinite scroller (up and down) for a project at work, I can tell you why they are not common: Appending to a page is *easy* (hence so many plugins about that scroll down), but prepending *and retaining the scrolling position* takes a lot of hard work :)

Comment: ^Have to agree, and I've yet to see a way a plugin could be made for it as every site is different. I've always had to build these from scratch. Kinda like data table plugins, they're useful, but only if you build everything around that plugin, and to often, that's just not an option. It's just easier to write your own and will save you time in the end.

Comment: I guess I will have to build my own then! Mine also has to be bi-directional. Do you guys have any tips for this? I'm using JQuery and JQuery UI already on the same page

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ui-element-samples/tree/gh-pages/infinite-scroller - this seems to address the problem. Yet to evaluate how good it is. Old post, I know - but, problem still exists.